# How to avoid using readlines()?

Tags: python, list, readlines

I need to deal with super large txt input files, and I usually use .readlines() to first read the whole file, and turn it into a list.

I know it's really memory-cost and can be quite slow, but I also need to make use of LIST characteristics to manipulate the specific lines, like below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os,sys
import glob
import commands
import gzip

path= '/home/xxx/scratch/'
fastqfiles1=glob.glob(path+'*_1.recal.fastq.gz')

for fastqfile1 in fastqfiles1:
    filename = os.path.basename(fastqfile1)
    job_id = filename.split('_')[0]
    fastqfile2 = os.path.join(path+job_id+'_2.recal.fastq.gz') 

    newfastq1 = os.path.join(path+job_id+'_1.fastq.gz') 
    newfastq2 = os.path.join(path+job_id+'_2.fastq.gz') 

    l1= gzip.open(fastqfile1,'r').readlines()
    l2= gzip.open(fastqfile2,'r').readlines()
    f1=[]
    f2=[]
    for i in range(0,len(l1)):
        if i % 4 == 3:
           b1=[ord(x) for x in l1[i]]
           ave1=sum(b1)/float(len(l1[i]))
           b2=[ord(x) for x in str(l2[i])]
           ave2=sum(b2)/float(len(l2[i]))
           if (ave1 >= 20 and ave2>= 20):
              f1.append(l1[i-3])
              f1.append(l1[i-2])
              f1.append(l1[i-1])
              f1.append(l1[i])
              f2.append(l2[i-3])
              f2.append(l2[i-2])
              f2.append(l2[i-1])
              f2.append(l2[i])
    output1=gzip.open(newfastq1,'w')
    output1.writelines(f1)
    output1.close()
    output2=gzip.open(newfastq2,'w')
    output2.writelines(f2)
    output2.close()
```

In general, I'm trying to read every 4th line of the whole text, but if the 4th line meets the desired condition, I'll append these 4 lines into the text.
So can I avoid readlines() to achieve this?
thx

EDIT:
Hi, actually I myself found a better way:

```
import commands
 l1=commands.getoutput('zcat ' + fastqfile1).splitlines(True)
 l2=commands.getoutput('zcat ' + fastqfile2).splitlines(True)
```

I think 'zcat' is super fast....
It took around 15min to readlines, while only 1 minute to just zcat...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can refactor your code to read through the file linearly, then you can just say `for line in file` to iterate through each line of the file without reading it all into memory at once.  But, since your file access looks more complicated, you could use a *generator* to replace `readlines()`.  One way to do this would be to use [`itertools.izip`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) or `itertools.izip_longest`:

```
def four_at_a_time(iterable):
    """Returns an iterator that returns a 4-tuple of objects at a time from the
       given iterable"""
    args = [iter(iterable) * 4]
    return itertools.izip(*args)
...
l1 = four_at_a_time(gzip.open(fastqfile1, 'r'))
l2 = four_at_a_time(gzip.open(fastqfile2, 'r'))
for i, x in enumerate(itertools.izip(l1, l2))
    # x is now a 2-tuple of 4-tuples of lines (one 4-tuple of lines from the first file,
    # and one 4-tuple of lines from the second file).  Process accordingly.
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way would be to,

(pseudocode, may contain errors, for illustrative purposes only)

```
    a=gzip.open()
    b=gzip.open()

    last_four_a_lines=[]
    last_four_b_lines=[]

    idx=0

    new_a=[]
    new_b=[]

    while True:
      la=a.readline()
      lb=b.readline()
      if (not la) or (not lb):
        break

      if idx % 4==3:
        a_calc=sum([ something ])/len(la)
        b_calc=sum([ something ])/len(lb)
        if a_calc and b_calc:
          for line in last_four_a_lines:
          new_a.append(line)
          for line in last_four_b_lines:
          new_b.append(line)

      last_four_a_lines.append(la)
      del(last_four_a_lines[0])
      last_four_b_lines.append(lb)
      del(last_four_b_lines[0])
      idx+=1
a.close()
b.close()
```

Comment: This is a simple way, Adam's suggestion is a better way

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) to iterate over the lines in the file, which would return a count and a line each iteration:

```
with open(file_name) as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i % 4 == 3:
            print i, line
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to print all lines containing `foo` and the previous 3 lines:

```
f = open(...)
prevlines = []
for line in f:
  prevlines.append(line)
  del prevlines[:-4]
  if 'foo' in line:
    print prevlines
```

If you are reading 2 files at a time (with an equal number of lines), do it like this:

```
f1 = open(...)
f2 = open(...)
prevlines1 = []
for line1 in f1:
  prevlines1.append(line1)
  del prevlines1[:-4]
  line2 = f2.readline()
  prevlines2.append(line2)
  del prevlines2[:-4]
  if 'foo' in line1 and 'bar' in line2:
    print prevlines1, prevlines2
```

Answer (score 0):

Tricky, because you actually have two files you are processing simultaneously.

You can use the fileinput module to efficiently parse a file one line at a time. It can be used to parse a list of files too, and you can use the fileinput.nextfile() method within the block to alternate through several files in parallel, consuming one line from each file at a time.

The fileinput.lineno() method will even give you the current line number in the current file. You could use temporary lists in the loop body to keep track of your 4-line blocks.

Totally untested ad-hoc code, possibly based on a misunderstanding of what your code does, follows:

```
f1 = []
f2 = []
for line in fileinput(filename1, filename2):
    if fileinput.filename() = filename1:
        f1.append(line)
    else:
        f2.append(line)
        if fileinput.lineno() % 4 == 3:
            doMyProcesing()
            f1 = []; f2 = []
    fileinput.nextfile()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that improving the obtention of l1 and l2 isn't sufficient: you must improve your code globally

I propose:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys
import gzip

path= '/home/xxx/scratch/'

def gen(gfa,gfb):
    try:
        a = (gfa.readline(),gfa.readline(),gfa.readline(),gfa.readline())
        b = (gfb.readline(),gfb.readline(),gfb.readline(),gfb.readline())
        if sum(imap(ord,a[3]))/float(len(a[3])) >= 20 \
           and sum(imap(ord,b[3]))/float(len(b[3])) >= 20:
            yield (a,b)
    except:
        break

for fastqfile1 in glob.glob(path + '*_1.recal.fastq.gz') :
    pji = path + os.path.basename(fastqfile1).split('_')[0] # pji = path + job_id

    gf1= gzip.open(fastqfile1,'r')
    gf2= gzip.open(os.path.join(pji + '_2.recal.fastq.gz'),'r')

    output1=gzip.open(os.path.join(pji + '_1.fastq.gz'),'w')
    output2=gzip.open(os.path.join(pji + '_2.fastq.gz'),'w')

    for lines1,lines2 in gen(gf1,gf2):
        output1.writelines(lines1)
        output2.writelines(lines2)

    output1.close()
    output2.close()
```

It should diminish the execution's time by 30 %. Pure guess.

PS:

code

```
if sum(imap(ord,a[3]))/float(len(a[3])) >= 20 \
   and sum(imap(ord,b[3]))/float(len(b[3])) >= 20:
```

is executed more rapidly rather than

```
ave1 = sum(imap(ord,a[3]))/float(len(a[3])) 
ave2 = sum(imap(ord,b[3]))/float(len(b[3]))
if ave1 >= 20 and ave2 >=20:
```

because if **ave1** isn't greater than 20, the object **ave2** isn't evaluated.